# How to create a conditional renderUI in Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am unable to create a conditional sidebar menu via renderMenu because the if statement fails. "Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero".

I found [conditional RenderUI R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092705/conditional-renderui-r-shiny) and [Conditional panel in Shiny dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925585/conditional-panel-in-shiny-dashboard) but neither are what I am looking for. A conditional panel might work in this instance but in the long run I will need to be able to do this server side.

```
    if (interactive()) {
  library(ggplot2)
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(shinipsum)

  ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenuOutput("plotDataVHA"),
      sidebarMenuOutput("tabSelector")
    ),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "facilities",
              fluidRow(box(
                uiOutput("selectedFacilityTime")
              ))),
      tabItem(tabName = "service",
              fluidRow(box(
                uiOutput("selectedFacilityYyCases")
              )))
    ))
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$renderedSelectedFacilityTime <- renderPlot({
      random_ggplot(type = "line")
    })
    output$selectedFacilityTime <- renderUI({
      plotOutput("renderedSelectedFacilityTime")
    })

    output$renderedFacilityYyCases <- renderPlot({
      random_ggplot(type = "bar")
    })
    output$selectedFacilityYyCases <- renderUI({
      plotOutput("renderedFacilityYyCases")
    })

    output$tabSelector <- renderMenu({
      sidebarMenu(id = "test",
                  menuItem(
                    text = "Chart data",
                    menuSubItem(
                      text = "Facilities",
                      tabName = "facilities",
                      selected = TRUE
                    ),
                    menuSubItem(
                      text = "Service & Specialty",
                      tabName = "service",
                      icon = NULL
                    )
                  ))
    })

    output$plotDataVHA <- renderMenu({
      if (input$test == "facilities") {
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          text = "VHA data",
          menuSubItem(
            text = "None",
            selected = TRUE,
            icon = NULL
          ),
          menuSubItem(text = "Mean", icon = NULL)
        )
      )
    }
     })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

When working properly the menu "VHA data" should only be visible when the submenu "facilities" is selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question. The reason you were getting the `argument is of length zero` error is because you are rendering both menus on the server side through `renderMenu()`. So when the app starts, `input$test` doesn't have a value assigned to it. You can avoid this by using `req()` which will evaluate the test `input$test == "facilities"` only after `input$test` has been initiated.

Now for the menu to only appear when another submenu is selected, you want to create the menu independently of `renderMenu()`. It is better to evaluate the condition in a normal `reactive()` and then pass this reactive function as input to `renderMenu()`. Finally, to remove the menu when `input$test == "facilities"` is `FALSE`, you can render an empty html container.

Here is the updated code:

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(shinipsum)

  ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenuOutput("plotDataVHA"),
      sidebarMenuOutput("tabSelector")
    ),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "facilities",
              fluidRow(box(
                uiOutput("selectedFacilityTime")
              ))),
      tabItem(tabName = "service",
              fluidRow(box(
                uiOutput("selectedFacilityYyCases")
              )))
    ))
  )

  server <- function(input, session, output) {
    output$renderedSelectedFacilityTime <- renderPlot({
      random_ggplot(type = "line")
    })
    output$selectedFacilityTime <- renderUI({
      plotOutput("renderedSelectedFacilityTime")
    })

    output$renderedFacilityYyCases <- renderPlot({
      random_ggplot(type = "bar")
    })
    output$selectedFacilityYyCases <- renderUI({
      plotOutput("renderedFacilityYyCases")
    })

    output$tabSelector <- renderMenu({
      sidebarMenu(id = "test",
                  menuItem(
                    text = "Chart data",
                    menuSubItem(
                      text = "Facilities",
                      tabName = "facilities",
                      selected = TRUE
                    ),
                    menuSubItem(
                      text = "Service & Specialty",
                      tabName = "service",
                      selected = FALSE,
                      icon = NULL
                    )
                  ))
    })

    make_menu <- reactive({
      cat("Current submenu selected: ", input$test, "\n\n")

      if (req(input$test) == "facilities") {
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          text = "VHA data",
          menuSubItem(
            text = "None",
            selected = TRUE,
            icon = NULL
          ),
          menuSubItem(text = "Mean", icon = NULL)
        )
      )
      } else {
        # return an empty HTML container
        div()
      } 
    })

    output$plotDataVHA <- renderMenu({
        make_menu()
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer to both aspects of my question. Much appreciated.