# Startup evaluation of server-side reactive

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I need a reactive variable (declared server-side) available after start-up. Using what I learned here [How to create a conditional renderUI in Shiny dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598536/how-to-create-a-conditional-renderui-in-shiny-dashboard/57600134#57600134) I tried wrapping in `reactive()` before defining the UI but no luck. Moving topValuesSelector to the UI inside a `conditionalPanel` would work except conditional panels apparently do not like the `%in%` operator (a separate issue that I also tried to resolve w/o success).

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(shinydashboardPlus)

  ui <-
    dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeaderPlus(left_menu = tagList(
      dropdownBlock(
        id = "prefDropdown",
        title = "Preferences",
        icon = NULL,
        badgeStatus = NULL,
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "prefDropdown",
          label = NULL,
          choices = c("Pareto",
                      "Legend on chart",
                      "Cases/1K uniques",
                      "Top 10 only"),
          selected = c("Pareto", "Cases/1K uniques", "Top 10 only")
        ),
        uiOutput("topValues")
      )
    )),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(fluidRow(box(
      title = "Top",
      textOutput("topN")
    ))))
  server <- function(input, output) {
    topValuesSelector <- reactive({
      if ("Top 10 only" %in% input$prefDropdown) {
        numericInput(
          inputId = "topValues",
          label = NULL,
          width = "25%",
          value = 10,
          min = 1,
          max = 30,
          step = 1
        )
      }
    })
    output$topValues <- renderUI({
      topValuesSelector()
    })

    observe({
      if ("Top 10 only" %in% input$prefDropdown) {
        output$topN <- renderText(input$topValues)
      } else{
        output$topN <- renderText(100)
      }
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

The intent is for the initial value of "topValues" to be 10 with this value immediately available. However, no value is available which causes an error. Using `req()` avoids the error by pausing execution but that is not a viable approach because "topValues" is needed for a plot. So no plot until selecting "prefDropdown".

Comment: ```==``` is not helpful because ```checkboxGroupInput()``` returns multiple values. Using ```req()``` does not address the problem. I am not getting an error; I am in a quandary because "topValues" is not defined until the user clicks on the drop-down block.

Comment: Sorry, misread it as a normal selection ...

Comment: When I run this code it runs without any error and shows the 10 filled in automatically. Are you sure your error isn't somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @AdamSampson: You are seeing a 10 in the text window titled "Top"?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. This problem is quite hard to follow because I have had to figure out what each step is supposed to look like. Now I can see the issue.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that `input$topValues` does not yet exist until you click on Preferences. All you have to do to activate the value is to click on preferences. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that `input$topValues` does not exist until you click on the Preferences button. Since the UI element isn't needed it hasn't been created yet.

In order to work around that you can create a variable that detects whether or not the input is available and if not use a default value.

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(shinydashboardPlus)

  ui <-
    dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeaderPlus(left_menu = tagList(
      dropdownBlock(
        id = "prefDropdown",
        title = "Preferences",
        icon = NULL,
        badgeStatus = NULL,
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "prefDropdown",
          label = NULL,
          choices = c("Pareto",
                      "Legend on chart",
                      "Cases/1K uniques",
                      "Top 10 only"),
          selected = c("Pareto", "Cases/1K uniques", "Top 10 only")
        ),
        uiOutput("topValues")
      )
    )),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(fluidRow(box(
      title = "Top",
      textOutput("topN")
    ))))
  server <- function(input, output) {
    ## We want to use the same default value in two places so create a var
    default_value <- 10
    topValuesSelector <- reactive({
      if ("Top 10 only" %in% input$prefDropdown) {
        numericInput(
          inputId = "topValues",
          label = NULL,
          width = "25%",
          value = default_value, ## Change to use the default value
          min = 1,
          max = 30,
          step = 1
        )
      }
    })
    output$topValues <- renderUI({
      topValuesSelector()
    })
    ## Create a variable that is the default value unless the input is available
    myTopN <- reactive({
      if(length(input$topValues)>0){
        return(input$topValues)
      }
      return(default_value)
    })
    observe({
      if ("Top 10 only" %in% input$prefDropdown) {
        # output$topN <- renderText(input$topValues)
        output$topN <- renderText(myTopN()) ## Use our new variable instead of the input directly
      } else{
        output$topN <- renderText(100)
      }
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

There are a couple of other things going on with your code. Notice that `"Top 10 only" %in% input$prefDropdown` will not do what you think it is doing. You have to check to see if `"Top 10 only"` is TRUE... I'll leave you there to start another question if you get stuck again.